# Getting an element from a xaml file without using the x:Name property

Tags: c#, xaml, textblock

So I have a couple of Elements I want to use in my c# class. These are a few lines of my xaml document that I want to extract the elements from:

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="diastolic17" FontSize="10" Foreground="Ivory" Grid.Row="19"
             Grid.Column="4"
             TextAlignment="Center">0</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="diastolic18" FontSize="10" Foreground="Ivory" Grid.Row="20"
             Grid.Column="4"
             TextAlignment="Center">98</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="diastolic19" FontSize="10" Foreground="Ivory" Grid.Row="21"
             Grid.Column="4"
             TextAlignment="Center">88</TextBlock>
```

They are all in the same namespace. I used to just use the x:Name property to get the TextBlocks but the problem is that I now have a huge list of TextBlocks, and I doubt the only way to do it is by typing each Textblock's name. If anyone could clarify how they would handle this? Simple solutions would be preffered, I'm a novice programmer and this is for a school project.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"?

Comment: In general when using WPF and MVVM: if you need a name of a control in code, or need to refer to a control in code, you might need to redesign the dependencies.

Comment: I just mean "get the element" actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to refer to a lot of controls you could group them in a single control (stackpanel, grid, ...) and access the controls by enumerating the child controls of the container.

An alternative is to [use data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). That way you probably don't need to refer to the controls at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use method `FindVisualChildren`. It traverses through Visual Tree and find your desired control.

This should do the trick

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
if (depObj != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
        {
            yield return (T)child;
        }

        foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
        {
            yield return childOfChild;
        }
    }
}
}
```

then you enumerate over the controls like so

```
foreach (TextBlock tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(window))
{
    // do something with tb here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where does the "window" come from in the foreach loop?

Comment: Is it from the Window class?