# How can i access grid column on the Main Window in which a User Control is located from the User Control Code Behind

Tags: wpf, grid, user-controls

I was hoping someone could help me please.

I have a user control placed within a column of the main window and I wish to access the Column width and amend it from the user control code behind.
I can achieve this if I know the x:name of the Column as follows:

```
((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).ColumnName.Width = new GridLength(55, GridUnitType.Pixel);
```

I was wondering, is there a way to achieve the same thing if I do not know the name of the containing Column?

The user control requires a min and max width and the width can be increased within these limits using a GridSplitter. The user control can also be pinned open or closed to a width of 55. The only way I have been able to achieve this is to set main window Column width, minWidth and MaxWidth. But these need amending when the user control in closed. If there is a better way to achieve this without need to have knowledge of the containing grid I would love some pointers.

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. A control must not have any knowledge of the fact that it is contained in a grid column. Why does it not set its own Width, and lives in a column with `Width="auto"`.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your prompt response. I have added some additional detail to my question which I hope clarifies my situation

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using `FindVisualChild` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16507470/13009649).
But I think you will need some info to filter out your column if there is more than one.

Go through the grid and check for your the one you need with something like this.

```
foreach (Grid grid in FindVisualChildren<Grid>(App.Current.MainWindow))
{
  foreach (ColumnDefinition item in grid.ColumnDefinitions)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Width);
  }
}
```

Comment: A Grid column is not a Visual.

Comment: @Clemens Please check the edit. It might not be the ideal way to do it.